# Accessing Multi Dimensional Array throws Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
class MDArrayDemo
{
  public static void Main()
  {
      string [,] array1 = new string[2, 2];
      array1[0,0] = "Subhadra";
      array1[0,1] = "Leon";
      array1[0,2] = "Maria";
      array1[1,0] = "Shawn";
      array1[1,1] = "Chantel";
      array1[1,2] = "Cheryl";
      array1[2,0] = "Nithya";
      array1[2,1] = "Suresh";
      array1[2,2] = "Kittu";
      Console.WriteLine("My Family {0}\n, {1}\n, {2}",array1 [0,0],array1 [0,1],array1 [0,2]);
      Console.WriteLine("Pseudos {0}\n, {1}\n, {2}",array1 [1,0],array1 [1,1],array1 [1,2]);
      Console.WriteLine("Vile {0}\n, {1}\n, {2}",array1 [2,0],array1 [2,1],array1 [2,2]);
     }
   }
```

This code throws an `Array out of bounds-Exception`.

Where did I go wrong, is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: At least format your code

Comment: Array size is 4 (00,01,10,11) and you are setting values to 0,2. which is out of bound. you have 2D array but you are assuming it 3D array. which is the problem.

Comment: Array index starts at 0, so if you declare [2,2] you get array of 2X2. So to add elements to array you have just 2 spots starting from zero `[0,0][0,1]` & `[1,0][1,1]`. Check @Nikhil Agrawal 's answer

Answer (score 1):

You have defined array with size `[2,2]` where you can add 4 values. But you added 9 values so change your `Array` declaration line to:

```
string [,] array1 = new string[3, 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define an array of `[2,2]` that means size 2x2 which means indices (0,1) only, not 2.

i.e

```
  array1[2,0] = "Nithya";
```

is you first exception

Answer (score 0):

Declare your array of size `3,3` whose indexes will be `0,1,2` which you require.

```
string[,] array1 = new string[3, 3];
```

Always remember Index are zero based i.e. they start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an array by your code

```
string [,] array1 = new string[2, 2];
```

means you are creating an array with the size of two elements in each dimension

> Arrays are zero indexed: an array with n elements is indexed from 0 to
>   n-1.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
string [,] array1 = new string[n, n];

x     y
0  ,  0
...
...
n-1, n-1
```

This means you start counting your elements from zero (in your code n = 2):

```
x y
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

If you want to create 3 elements in each dimension, this should be your code:

```
string [,] array1 = new string[3, 3];
```